# Python Find duplicates across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

How do i filter a dataframe to only show rows with duplicates across multiple columns?

Example dataframe:

```
col1 col2 col3
A1    B1   C1
A1    B1   C1
A1    B1   C2
A2    B2   C2
```

Expected output:

```
col1 col2 col3
A1    B1   C1
A1    B1   C1
```

My attempt:

```
df[df.duplicated(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], keep=False)]
```

but this does not give expected outcome.

Comment: seems to work for me

Answer (score 7):

Your attempt `df[df.duplicated(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], keep=False)]` works in my testing. You can leave out the column names:

```
df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]
```